# When to use SymPy CoordSys3D vs ReferenceFrame

Tags: sympy

To do dynamics, I've been using SymPy ReferenceFrame (under the Physics module). When I recently looked into SymPy CoordSys3D (under the Matrices module), I find a lot of similar functionality and methods: defining new frames / systems as rotations from existing ones, expressing the same vector in different frames, etc. When is CoordSys3D better to use than ReferenceFrame?